# 会 inside 我们联系不多,偶尔会打个电话。is used with 偶尔

Tags: grammar, time

> 我们联系不多,偶尔会打个电话。

I have no problem understanding 我们联系不多 but currently I've been confused with 会 which is used at 偶尔会打个电话.

Parsing this sentence, 偶尔(ocassionally)会(will)打个电话(to make a phone call) is gained.

For me , the original sentence is like a following one.

> We don't contact each other frequently, and we **will** just talk on phone-line **occasionally**.

This grammatical structure of "will" and "occasionally" seems as non-existent one in English grammar.

Can you enumerate some resemble Chinese phrases each of which uses 会(will) with term(s) like 偶尔? so that I can get accustomed to this kind of grammatical structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply translate [会](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/1783) as "would" and you'll have no problem

> [会](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/1783): will; shall; **would**; be likely to

> 我们联系不多,偶尔会打个电话。

> We don't connect often. However, we would occasionally talk over the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Damn, gpt3.5 has shown me some example-sentences within 10 seconds.

Phrase: 我们偶尔会一起吃饭。

Pinyin: Wǒmen ǒuěr huì yìqǐ chīfàn.

English: We will occasionally eat together.

Phrase: 她偶尔会买些小礼物送给朋友。

Pinyin: Tā ǒuěr huì mǎi xiē xiǎo lǐwù sòng gěi péngyou.

English: She will occasionally buy small gifts to give to her friends.

Phrase: 我们偶尔会去看电影。

Pinyin: Wǒmen ǒuěr huì qù kàn diànyǐng.

English: We will occasionally go see a movie.

Phrase: 他们偶尔会去旅游。

Pinyin: Tāmen ǒuěr huì qù lǚyóu.

English: They will occasionally go on trips.